# Знаки препинания в сложноподчинённом предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания ставится в сложноподчинённом предложении с союзом "если", когда он [этот самый союз] обозначает не условие,а участвует в выражении решительного утверждения, чтобы подчеркнуть что-л., обратить внимание на что-л или участвует в выражении сопоставления с другим предложением или противопоставления,а также употребляется в значении уступительного союза.
Примеры:

> А если кто и виноват в случившемся то только я ( союз участвует в выражении решительного утверждения).

> Если морской климат мягкий то континентальный гораздо суровее (союз участвует в выражении сопоставления или противопоставления с другим предложением).

> Если он даже бесконечно рад то никогда открыто этого не покажет ( если — уступительный союз)

Answer (score 0):

О первых двух предложениях вы какой-то бред написали, уж извините. Это обычные придаточные условия. Вы, случайно, не родственник Розенталя?.. Шутка. Что касается последнего предложения. Виды придаточных — это классификация придаточной части по общему значению. Действительно, придаточная часть в третьем предложении имеет общее значение и условия, и уступки. В обоих случаях пунктуация одинакова. Можете считать данное придаточное придаточным условия или уступки, или условия-уступки.

Comment: Это я не бред написал. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8 — здесь было указано значения союза если.

Answer (score 0):

1. Практически перед второй частью составного союза ***ЕСЛИ...ТО*** тире не ставится, так как **указательного** местоимения и **запятой** вполне **достаточно** для выражения отношений **различного** вида. Это можно увидеть **по примерам из [Нацкорпуса](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnUiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQsCDQtdGB0LvQuCDQutGC0L4g0LgwAA==).**

*А если кто и уйдет, **то** не дальше опушки...*

*А если кто и ездил в Москву, **то** тот с теми кругами, в которых мы жили, не общался.*

2. Тире чаще ставится перед местоимением ***ТАК*** (обозначение увеличенной паузы):

*— Ну, сделали имя, играют в эти игры, сами, понимаете, в это нисколько, конечно, не верят, **а если кто и верит** — **так** это уже просто полные....*  Михаил Веллер. Ножик Сережи Довлатова (1997)

Answer (score -2):

ЕСЛИ. I. союз. 1. (в начале придат. предл.). Участвует в выражении реально возможного условия, в зн.: в том случае, когда. Е. надо будет, я позову тебя. Е. хочешь, можешь прочитать письмо. Посетите домик Лермонтова, е. будете в Пятигорске. // (в придат. предл. с частицей бы). Участвует в выражении желательного, предполагаемого или противоречащего действительности условия. Опасности можно было бы избежать, е. бы знать заранее, чего бояться. Я бы обязательно заблудился, е. бы прохожий не показал мне дорогу. Е. бы его наказали, ему было бы обидно. // (в придат. предл. с частицей уж). Участвует в выражении условия, которое является причиной или обоснованием того, о чём говорится в главном предложении, в зн.: так как, раз. Е. уж я сумел, то ты тем более сумеешь это сделать. Надо слушаться, е. уж врач предписал покой. Не переживай, е. уж так случилось! 2. (во вводных предл. и словосочет.). Участвует в выражении оттенка условности, предположительности. Е. не ошибаюсь, мы где-то с вами встречались. Налейте мне ещё чашку чаю, е. можно. Обстановка в зале, е. можно так сказать, накалилась до предела. За лесом, е. свернуть левее, дорога в сторону станции. 3. (в начале придат. предл. обычно с союзами: а... и, и). Участвует в выражении решительного утверждения, чтобы подчеркнуть что-л., обратить внимание на что-л. А е. кто и виноват в случившемся, то только я один. Е. кто и желал ему по-настоящему добра, то это его сестра. 4. (в начале придат. предл.). Участвует в выражении сопоставления с другим предложением или противопоставления ему. Е. морской климат мягкий, то континентальный значительно суровее. Е. брусника растёт в сырых тенистых местах, то земляника предпочитает места открытые, солнечные. Е. его самого уважали, то к друзьям его относились с оглядкой. 5. (в придат. предл. с частицами: и, же, даже). Употр. в значении уступительного союза. Е. даже он бесконечно рад, то никогда этого открыто не показывает. Я жду е. и не одобрения, то по крайней мере ободряющих слов. II. в зн. частицы. 1. (в начале вопросит. предл., обычно в сочет. с частицами: а, а что). Употр. в зн.: а вдруг. А что е. он и вправду согласится? Не унывай, всё обойдётся! - А е. нет? 2. (в простом предл. с частицей бы, обычно с междометиями: ах, о). Участвует в выражении сильного желания. Е. бы наконец кончились все волнения! О, е. бы мне удалось совершить задуманное! Ах, е. бы утро скорее настало! ◊ Если бы да кабы. Шутл. Употр. для выражения сожаления о чём-л. несбывшемся или несбыточном, не осуществившемся, невозможном. Если бы я знал! Если бы знать! (обычно в ответной реплике). Употребляется в зн.: я и сам не знаю (не знал). Что это там? - Е. бы я знал! Если (уж) на то пошло. Если так нужно, поскольку дело коснулось (чего-л.). Если уж на то пошло, теперь вы меня послушайте! <Если (и) не..., то..., в зн. союза. Оттепели нынче если и не каждый день, то достаточно часто. Если хотите (хочешь); если угодно, в зн. вводн. словосоч. Пожалуй, возможно. Он, если хотите, несколько самоуверен. Старик этот, если угодно, своего рода провидец. Я, если хотите знать, всегда это предполагал.